# Сборка php 5.5 для win64

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста где найти сборку php5.5 для win64. Своими силами найти не удалось пока. На [оф. сайте](http://windows.php.net/download/) как я понял только для win32. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

там как бы есть она. VC11 x64 Non Thread Safe (2013-Oct-17 00:30:10) это не то?

Comment: что значит как бы? Любой из дистрибутивов, которые есть на этой странице при скачивании выдает, что это win32

Comment: ты смотри на x64 и x86, а не на win32

Comment: вы правы. Нужно качать x64. Но для многоядерных процессов лучше прользовать Thread Safe.